# How to mention two intent filters for An activity in android

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am writing  an application to open HTML files so i am mentioning the intent filter  for activity as

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
        </intent-filter>
```

,for this app, no launcher icon will be there.but i want my application to be as launcher app and when i open the app i want to display some info about application,and then he open the app by html file then i want to do different functionality (parsing the html).any ideas?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can specify more than one `<intent-filter>` between the `<activity>` tags:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: yes above is correct..
in Activity we  can get the the action by using following code and we can decide the flow where it should go.
                Intent i = getIntent();
  
              String action =  i.getAction(); 
             if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.MAIN")) {
   //one logic 
  } 
else{
//another logic
}

Comment: This works perfectly. I couldn't find it in the Android docs anywhere, but it seems like a common use case.